# Xelatex: Section fontsize

Tags: xetex, titlesec

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\bfseries\fontsize{20pt}{0}\selectfont}{Chapter \thechapter.}{10pt}{}
```

I can modify the Chapter normally.
However, it is not possible in section and subsection.
According to the specification of the paper section must be 16pt bold font, and subsection must be 14pt bold font.

```
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseriesfontsize{16pt}{0}\selectfont}{\thesection}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{0}\selectfont}{\thesubsection}{10pt}{}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: it will be a lot easier for people to help you if you provide an example that shows the problem, it is hard to debug disconnected fragments with no example of their use. Possibly unrelated but setting the baseline to 0pt which you do in each case seems odd?

Comment: `\bfseriesfontsize` is presumably a typo for `\bfseries\fontsize` do you have that in your real document?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle　Sorry, I posted the wrong one. The real content is \bfseries\fontsize. What I'm curious about is that it seems \bfseries\fontsize{16pt}{0}\selectfont is not working properly

Comment: @user246264, please provide a compilable example (including \begin{document} and \end{document}). You can edit your question to post the correct one.

Comment: that is why it is so useful to post a real example. There is nothing in the code you have posted so far that shows what you did or what went wrong. make a small complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that has a `\section` that shows the problem.

Comment: what does "not working properly" mean? did you get an error, is the font a diffeent size? How did you measure the font size you got?  so far you have posted a fragment with an undefined command, not shown any example input or output and not shown any log. No one can help you unless you give some information about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Completing your fragments to an example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\bfseries\fontsize{20pt}{0}\selectfont}{Chapter \thechapter.}{10pt}{}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\fontsize{16pt}{0}\selectfont}{\thesection}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{0}\selectfont}{\thesubsection}{10pt}{}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

\section{aaa}
zz
\end{document}
```

If you use this with pdflatex then you get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <16> not available
(Font)              size <17.28> substituted on input line 12.
```

and the `\showoutput` log confirms the **aaa** heading uses 17.28pt font

```
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/17.28 a
```

This is due to historic compatibility issues forcing Computer Modern to be used in a fixed set of sizes. You can use the `fix-cm` package or choose a different font package eg `Latin modern` (commented out in the example above).

However you indicated you are using xelatex, which already defaults to the OpenType Latin Modern and 16pt font is used in that case:

```
....\TU/lmr/bx/n/16 aaa
```

Comment: unrelated but `\fontsize{20pt}{0}\selectfont` says to use 20pt font on lines that are 0pt apart which can never work. So long as your titles are single line this doesn't matter but if you have a long title that needs to line break, this will make horrible output. `\fontsize{20pt}{22pt}\selectfont` would be more normal.